# VB6 to C# InsTR function conversion issue

Tags: c#, vb6

Is the VB6 code

```
i = InStr(1, strText, "Mc", CompareMethod.Binary)
    If (i <> 0) And (i + 2 <= lngLength) Then Mid(strText, i + 2, 1) = UCase(Mid(strText, i + 2, 1))
```

doing the same as

```
i = strText.IndexOf("Mc");
    if ((i != 1) && (i + 2 <= lngLength))
    {
        strText = strText.Substring(i + 2, 1);
        strText = strText.ToUpper();            
    }
```

in C#? i is an int that has been initialized. Now I did make adjustment with the returned value if the comparisons are good from 0 in VB6 to 1 in C#.

Comment: `IndexOf` returns -1 for no match in C#.

Comment: I think `Mid(strText, i + 2, 1) = UCase(Mid(strText, i + 2, 1))` does not do what you expect it to. Are you sure you don't just want to `strText = strText.Replace("Mc", "MC")`?

Comment: Can you post an example of what is contained in strText as well as lngLength and Input as well as expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not doing the same. The assignment

```
Mid(strText, i + 2, 1) = UCase(Mid(strText, i + 2, 1))
```

replaces only *that part* (i.e. a single character at `i+2`) inside the string, and leaves the rest untouched. Your C# code throws the rest of the string away.

Since .NET strings are immutable, this approach cannot be directly translated.

The closest translation is to construct the string explicitly, i.e. to do

```
strText = strText.Substring(0, i + 1) +
    strText.Substring(i + 2, 1).ToUpper() +
    strText.Substring(i + 3);
```

However, doing this a lot inside a loop is very inefficient, which is why .NET offers the [`StringBuilder` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) for repeated constructions of strings. In general, VB6 code which manipulates strings in-place is best translated by using said `StringBuilder`.

That said, there is probably a simpler translation by going after the *intent* after the first code, rather than the letter. In both VB6 and C# you wouldn’t use `InStr` followed by substitution – you’d directly use `String.Replace`.

Also beware of the changed indices (C# and VB.NET are 0-based, VB6 may be 1-based).

Comment: I just feel like I need to continue using the VB6 code with an extern dll import instead. Can't even tell if the test is working as it should.

Comment: +1. I think VB6 strings are immutable too, but the `Mid` statement silently creates a new string and points `strText` at that new string. The VB6 string API design is excellent, so no-one ever got confused by immutable strings. Cannot say the same about C#. There are few parts of VB6 that are better than C#, but this is arguably one.

Comment: @MarkJ I haven’t touched it for ages but I’m 99.99% sure that VB6 strings are *not* immutable. Lots of low-level hacks used that fact. Byte manipulation with `LSet` was rampant, as was passing string pointers around and manipulating the byte sequence raw.

Comment: Fresh eyes looking this morning.. first thing that stands out with unit test is "Also beware of the changed indices (C# and VB.NET are 0-based, VB6 may be 1-based)"

Answer (score -1):

```
StringBuilder strText = new StringBuilder("Mcdonald");
int lngLength = strText.Length;
int i = strText.ToString().IndexOf("Mc");
if ((i != 1) && (i + 2 <= lngLength))
{
    strText[i + 2] = char.ToUpper(strText[i + 2]);
}
Console.WriteLine(strText.ToString()); // prints McDonald
```

EDIT: Basically, you don't have to get the string before/after the position at which the character is found and do a concatenation of it. `StringBuilder` helps to modify things in place (string as array of characters) and the `ToString` method joins the array of characters to a string.

Comment: That contains a lot of redundant code. To wit, `ToString()`, the check for `i + 2 <= lngLength`, come to think of it, the declaration of `lngLength`, and finally, the check for `i != 1` is wrong.

Comment: if index is returned -1 then what? @shahkalpesh

Comment: @Rezoan: It doesn't throw an error but isn't a valid output. I picked up what was present above (in terms of validation). The OP will have to put necessary checks to see if the string is found, at desired position etc. The answer guides the OP on how to modify string in place, using `StringBuilder`. Thanks.

Comment: When downvoting, please put in the reasons in the comment. Thanks.